# How do you specify source code files in OpenShift repo?

Tags: php, git, callback, openshift

I am trying to refer to a callback URL in my OpenShift application. The callback URL refers to a script which takes the user back to the application with the right OAuth access tokens for the Twitter API.

On localhost the callback URL works perfectly fine and the application works as required, however when trying to specify the same URL but on OpenShift it is returning a 404.

This is my site http://twittersearch-jbon0041.rhcloud.com/

**Callback URL on localhost:**

http://localhost/TwitterSearch/twitteroauth-master/callback.php

**Callback URL on OpenShift:**

http://twittersearch-jbon0041.rhcloud.com/54d8efc04382ecb1c900011c/app-root/runtime/repo/twitteroauth-master/callback.php

So I am thinking that this may because I am not specifying the URL correctly and the path to the repository on the OpenShift server is not correct. I tried looking around for the proper way to call a file on the server but no luck. I appreciate any help given!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback url should be `http://twittersearch-jbon0041.rhcloud.com/twitteroauth-master/callback.php`

This is the correct path to that file, but your application url does not seem to exist anymore.